# Understanding if its necessary to check both side from which limit is being approached for saying Limit exist after differentiating using LHoptial

Tags: calculus

When we apply L-hopital to any expression of form 0/0 or infinity/infinity ,do we not have to care about the right and left hand side of the limit ? We just need to focus on any one side for the limit to exist ? Like for example $limit_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{x-x^2}$ , do we not check how the limit is approach ( that is from right side of 0  (0^+ ) and from left side of zero (0^- )? We just differentiate and get the result as 1 ?

Comment: As written, the staatement uses the twosided limit. Twosided is typically also how the derivatives in question are definied.

Comment: Okay thanks @HagenvonEitzen , lets say in general if we given a limit to evaluate not necessary in indeterminate form , do we still need to check both the right hand side and left hand side of the limit and then say whether limit exists or not ?

Comment: We do, but a lot of the time we are lucky and the limits are easily evaluated without needing to consider the one sided limits individually. E.g. L'Hopital's rule will compute (in most formulations) the two sided limits by default

Comment: I see thanks understood